# Rails + Jasmine Issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, jasmine

I'm using [jasmine-rails](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-rails) for testing js.
I have created a dummy js test.
**spec/javascripts/foo_spec.coffee**

```
describe 'Foo', ->
  it 'does something', ->
    expect(1 + 1).toBe(2)
```

Through the browser `http://localhost:3000/specs` everything works like a charm.

But running from the command line `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake spec:javascript` throws up the error

```
drobazko@drobazko:~/www/help_desk$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake spec:javascript
Starting up a new ElasticSearch client with 
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.2.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/assertion_error.rb:10:in `<module:Matchers>'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.2.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/assertion_error.rb:2:in `<module:Shoulda>'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.2.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/assertion_error.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.2.0/lib/shoulda/matchers.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.2.0/lib/shoulda-matchers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
  /home/drobazko/www/help_desk/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/drobazko/www/help_desk/Rakefile:4:in `require'
  /home/drobazko/www/help_desk/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /home/drobazko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
Running `"/home/drobazko/.phantomjs/1.9.8/x86_64-linux/bin/phantomjs" "/home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jasmine-rails-0.10.7/lib/jasmine_rails/../assets/javascripts/jasmine-runner.js" "/home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/runner.html?spec="`
Running: /home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/runner.html?spec=
Wrong url scheme for WebSocket file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/undefined///faye
ERROR: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12: An invalid or illegal string was specified.
TRACE:
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 11910
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 14692
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 10339
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 4642
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 4310
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 4551
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 5261
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 384
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 137
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 5262
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 10344
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 3120
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 3232
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 3444
 -> file:///home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/assets/jasmine-specs.js: 3475 (in function "completed")
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file:///home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jasmine-rails-0.10.7/lib/assets/javascripts/jasmine-runner.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file:///home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jasmine-rails-0.10.7/lib/assets/javascripts/jasmine-runner.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file:///home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jasmine-rails-0.10.7/lib/assets/javascripts/jasmine-runner.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

rake aborted!
Error executing command: "/home/drobazko/.phantomjs/1.9.8/x86_64-linux/bin/phantomjs" "/home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jasmine-rails-0.10.7/lib/jasmine_rails/../assets/javascripts/jasmine-runner.js" "/home/drobazko/www/help_desk/tmp/jasmine/runner.html?spec="
/home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jasmine-rails-0.10.7/lib/jasmine_rails/runner.rb:72:in `run_cmd'
/home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jasmine-rails-0.10.7/lib/jasmine_rails/runner.rb:22:in `block in run'
/home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jasmine-rails-0.10.7/lib/jasmine_rails/runner.rb:49:in `override_rails_config'
/home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jasmine-rails-0.10.7/lib/jasmine_rails/runner.rb:9:in `run'
/home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jasmine-rails-0.10.7/lib/tasks/jasmine-rails_tasks.rake:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => spec:javascript
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
drobazko@drobazko:~/www/help_desk$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake spec:javascript
```

**jasmine.yml**

```
src_dir: "app/assets/javascripts"
css_dir: "app/assets/stylesheets"

src_files:
 - "application.{js.coffee,js,coffee}"

css_files:

spec_dir: spec/javascripts

helpers:
  - "helpers/**/*.{js.coffee,js,coffee}"
spec_files:
  - "**/*[Ss]pec.{js.coffee,js,coffee}"

tmp_dir: "tmp/jasmine"
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.1)
      actionpack (= 4.1.1)
      actionview (= 4.1.1)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.1)
      actionview (= 4.1.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.1)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.1)
      activemodel (= 4.1.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.1)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.3.7)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    aws-sdk (1.62.0)
      aws-sdk-v1 (= 1.62.0)
    aws-sdk-v1 (1.62.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    bonsai-elasticsearch-rails (0.0.4)
    builder (3.2.2)
    cancan (1.6.10)
    capybara (2.4.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    carrierwave (0.10.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    carrierwave-aws (0.5.0)
      aws-sdk (~> 1.58)
      carrierwave (~> 0.7)
    childprocess (0.5.5)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.0)
    cookiejar (0.3.2)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    database_cleaner (1.4.0)
    devise (3.4.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    elasticsearch (1.0.6)
      elasticsearch-api (= 1.0.6)
      elasticsearch-transport (= 1.0.6)
    elasticsearch-api (1.0.6)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-model (0.1.6)
      activesupport (> 3)
      elasticsearch (> 0.4)
      hashie
    elasticsearch-rails (0.1.6)
    elasticsearch-transport (1.0.6)
      faraday
      multi_json
    em-http-request (1.1.2)
      addressable (>= 2.3.4)
      cookiejar
      em-socksify (>= 0.3)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.3)
      http_parser.rb (>= 0.6.0)
    em-socksify (0.3.0)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.0.beta.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.7)
    execjs (2.3.0)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.0.1)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    faraday (0.9.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    faye (1.0.3)
      cookiejar (>= 0.3.0)
      em-http-request (>= 0.3.0)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.0)
      faye-websocket (>= 0.7.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.3.0)
    faye-rails (2.0.0)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0.0)
      faye (~> 1.0.1)
    faye-websocket (0.9.2)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.5.1)
    ffi (1.9.6)
    hashie (3.4.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jasmine-core (2.2.0)
    jasmine-rails (0.10.7)
      jasmine-core (>= 1.3, < 3.0)
      phantomjs (< 2.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      sprockets-rails
    jbuilder (2.2.7)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-turbolinks (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      turbolinks
    json (1.8.2)
    kaminari (0.16.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.5.1)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.18)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    phantomjs (1.9.8.0)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.1)
      actionpack (= 4.1.1)
      actionview (= 4.1.1)
      activemodel (= 4.1.1)
      activerecord (= 4.1.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.1)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.1.1)
      actionpack (= 4.1.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rakismet (1.5.0)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    remotipart (1.2.1)
    responders (1.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 4.2)
    rmagick (2.13.4)
    rspec-core (3.2.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.2.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.2.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-support (3.2.2)
    rubyzip (1.1.7)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.5)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 3.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    selenium-webdriver (2.44.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    shoulda-matchers (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    slim (3.0.2)
      temple (~> 0.7.3)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    slim-rails (3.0.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      slim (~> 3.0)
    sprockets (2.12.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    temple (0.7.5)
    thin (1.6.3)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    websocket (1.2.1)
    websocket-driver (0.5.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.1)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bonsai-elasticsearch-rails
  cancan
  capybara
  carrierwave
  carrierwave-aws
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  database_cleaner
  devise
  elasticsearch-model
  elasticsearch-rails
  factory_girl_rails
  faker (= 1.0.1)
  faye-rails (~> 2.0)
  jasmine-rails
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jdbc-mysql (= 5.1.28)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-turbolinks
  kaminari
  launchy
  minitest
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.13)
  rails (= 4.1.1)
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  rakismet
  remotipart (~> 1.2)
  rmagick
  rspec-rails (~> 3.0)
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  shoulda-matchers (~> 2.2.0)
  slim-rails
  thin
  turbolinks
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```